# Property value from Hibernate validator annotation not display the value when using message bundle file

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-validator

I´m using Hibernate Validator in one project, so my model class has this field.

```
@Size(max = 50, message = "A descrição deve conter no máximo {max} caracteres")
private String descricao;
```

If I use the field with the message key like this

```
@Size(max = 50, message = "ERRO.PUBLICIDADE.DESCRICAO_EXISTENTE")
private String descricao;
```

I got this validation message

[image]

And I have this key inside my message bundle file

```
ERRO.PUBLICIDADE.DESCRICAO.SIZE=A descrição deve conter no máximo {max} caracteres.
```

So what´s wrong?

I´m using Hibernate Validator 5.1.2

Comment: Care to translate the warning message?

Comment: The message is, The description needs to have {max} chacaracters

Comment: I think something is wrong with your example. To interpolate a message it needs to be embraces in {}. So it would be @Size(max = 50, message = "{ERRO.PUBLICIDADE.DESCRICAO_EXISTENTE}"). Then in our message bundle, the key does not match. You write - ERRO.PUBLICIDADE.DESCRICAO.SIZE. This might just be typos, but maybe not!?

Comment: @Hardy I put embraces in the key and don´t worked.

Comment: You really need to provide more context. What is you environment? How is Validator called? Which version are you using? How does the full example  look like?

Comment: @Hardy I put the version in the code, do you have one example working to show me?